# How to create Clone-Duplicate View?

Tags: android, view, android-view

In my android application, I want to create duplicate `ImageButton` of already created `Imagebutton`.

I want to create new `Imagebutton` programmatically having same widht, height, background, image src, margins etc. of already created button in XML file. In short, I want to create duplicate `ImageButton`.

I have try this

```
ImageButton mImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib);
Imagebutton duplicate = mImageButton;
```

But it only refer to the the `mImageButton`. So, change in `duplicate` also cause change in `mImageButton`.

Please help me out. Thank you...

Comment: you can create an array of image button

Answer (score 16):

You cannot clone views, the way to do it is to create your View each time.

You could always inflate the view multiple times from an XML or create a function to create the view programatically.

Inflation:

```
private void addImageButton(ViewGroup viewGroup) {    
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.ib, null);
    viewGroup.addView(v);
}
```

Programatically:

```
private void addImageButton(ViewGroup viewGroup) {    
    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context);
    viewGroup.addView(imageButton);
}
```

Comment: Any difference between inflation and adding a view?

Comment: @Vamsi inflating a view will set its attributes to whatever you set it to be in the XML, while creating a new view programatically will set it to default values that you may not want.
If you're going to be making many clones of complex views/layouts, I would recommend making an XML for it.

Comment: In my case i was an edittext therefore i had to cast it to edittext. I tried the first approach , but the result was just a normal edittext without any attributes i set in the xml . Any idea why is this happening ?

Answer (score -1):

Also be sure that you set unique id for each new clonned view.
Otherwise you can get this error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent.

You must call `removeView()` on the child's parent first.

`view.setId(int id)`;

Comment: Tried this on the cloned view but it changes the original view's ID too