# Duplicate a view programmatically from an already existing view

Tags: android, android-view

I was trying the following code and was getting an error because there is no such constructor defined.

`View v = new View(findViewById(R.id.divider));`

Is there any simple way to copy a view into another?

Comment: Hope this will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159211/how-do-i-clone-a-view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798826/duplicate-views-on-android-during-run-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Clone-Duplicate View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744039/how-to-create-clone-duplicate-view)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Apparently you cannot clone views as stated by these answers:

[How do I clone a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159211/how-do-i-clone-a-view)

[How to create Clone-Duplicate View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744039/how-to-create-clone-duplicate-view)

If you inflated the first view from XML the way to go seems to be inflating the second view from XML, too.

To inflate your view from XML put it into an extra layout file, e.g. "textview.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Then, inflate it from XML in your onCreate():

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
myLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: What if we require it in a function that outside onCreate() ?
any idea ?

Comment: @SyedHissaan Create a global variable to hold your context: `Context contextApp;`. Then in OnCreate, populate the variable: `contextApp = this`. In a function outside of OnCreate, where you would normally put, "this", instead put, "contextApp".

Comment: what about canvas libs, where xml doesn't exist?