# How to set an xml view to dynamically added android widgets?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, layout-inflater, dynamic-view

I have created custom buttons and edittexts, I require them in many activities . I want them all to look the same having a particular design .
Normally we set layouts to these widgets by `findViewById()` but in this case i am adding those edittexts dynamically.
I want to know if there is a way i can set layout to my edittext either in the class itself or after it's instantiation ?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. "Normally we set layouts to these widgets by `findViewById()`" – The `findViewById()` method is used to locate `View`s with a particular ID in a hierarchy. It's not inherently tied to XML layouts. "I want to know if there is a way i can set layout to my edittext" – What exactly do you mean by that? Do you mean you want to set an ID on your `EditText` that you can use with `findViewById()`?

Comment: I am sorry if i was not clear enough . Let me elaborate what i am trying to do .
We set views to their java declaration using findViewById() which points to a particular id in xml file where we have designed our button with properties like padding , margins, background. 
In my case i have created a created a custom class and i am adding it dynamically to my views . I can't therefore use findViewById to connect it to any view from xml. 
i was looking for a way to connect it to a view from an xml file so then it's now displayed with all those properties
let me know if i need to be more clear

Comment: It sounds like you want to inflate your `View`s from pre-defined layouts – where you've set the desired attributes' values – rather than directly instantiating them with `new`. Is that what you're doing currently? Instantiating with `new`?

Comment: yeah exactyly , currently i am doing that with `new` and i actually want to inflate my view from predefined attributes !

Comment: Kinda like this, then? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012476